# How to compare an optional field to a non-optional field in Realm queries?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to use the [Realm query api](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/crud/filter-data) in Swift to filter on the following Realm object:

```
public class Photo: Object {

    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var photoID: UUID
    @Persisted(indexed: true) var remoteDateLastUpdated: Date?
    @Persisted(indexed: true) var localDateLastUpdated: Date
}
```

Notice that the one of the `Date` fields is optional and the other is not. I am trying to query this object like so:

```
    let photosToPush = self.photos.where({
        $0.remoteDateLastUpdated != $0.localDateLastUpdated
    })
```

But I am getting the error **Cannot convert value of type Query<Date> to expected argument type 'Query<Date?>'**

How can I typecast this to make this query work?

Comment: Unwrap the optional parameter using `if let` or `guard` inside the closure

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't understand how to unwrap it since Query<Date?> is not an optional in itself, but also non-comparable to Query<Date>. Can you provide more guidance?

Comment: The query itself doesn't make sense. The `remoteDateLastUpdated` is an optional and can therefore be nil. So the query is asking realm to query a potentially nil property against a property that will never be nil. So no, that syntax doesn't work. e.g. The logic spelled out is - `If nil is not equal to  ???` - doesn't have a result. If you can explain the objective then we can probably tell you what will work.